# How to cluster documents based on overlapping identifiers?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining, hierarchical-clustering

I have 3.5M documents and each document has k unique identifiers. I need to cluster documents based on their similarity. Two documents are similar if they have m overlapping identifiers. m < k

If I pick any two documents in the cluster (for cluster size > 1), the must have at-least m-overlapping identifiers.

What is a fast way to do it. Also, I want to minimize the number of clusters.

Comment: Sounds a lot like DBSCAN to me.

Comment: Can DBSCAN fulfill this constraint: "If I pick any two documents in the cluster (for cluster size > 1), the must have at-least m-overlapping identifiers" ? 

Won't you agree this is closer to the clique problem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem

Comment: specifically: listing all maximal cliques

Comment: No, at that point it sounds more like classic complete-linkage hierarchical clustering (HAC) to me (which unfortunately scales really badly); and with your minimize constraint, it probably is set-cover and NP-hard.

Comment: How many of the 3.5M documents have *unique* sets of identifiers? Documents that have exactly the same identifiers should be treated as identical by the algorithm.

Comment: Yes. Not more than 5%.

Comment: If we look at the document set as an undirected graph where an edge exists between two vertices if they have more than m overlapping identifiers, doesn't the problem boil down to listing all maximal cliques? Bron–Kerbosch_algorithm 

Don't you agree? Would that be more efficient than CLINK?

Comment: Well, **give it a try**. But building the graph yields `O(n^2)` edges, and Bron-Kerbosch is in the easy version even `O(3^(n/3))` - not something you want to use on a large data set. Unsurprisingly: the clique problem is NP-complete. (HAC is only O(n^3); but doesn't solve the clique problem obviously) - you will have to settle for some approximation, not the full clique problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for **graph clustering**, which is a hard problem to solve.

[Here is an article](http://geza.kzoo.edu/~erdi/patent/Schaeffer07.pdf) about graph clustering, but you might find more/better info if you google for it.

As for "what is the fastest way to do it". It is next to impossible to answer as you don't give any information about the dataset or your environment. However, I do suspect that loading this into a graph database somehow, where some of which has graph clustering features built in, would get you far quite quickly.

For the general procedure to solve this problem, here is some pseudo-code:

```
define calculate_similarity(doc1, doc2)
    score = 0
    foreach identifier in doc1.identifiers 
        score += 1 if doc2.identifiers.contain(identifier)
    return score

similarity_double_hash = new hash(default = new Hash)
foreach document1 in all_documents
    foreach document2 in all_document
        next if document1 == document2
        similarity = calculate_similarity(document1,document2)
        similarity_double_hash[document1][document2] = similarity
        similarity_double_hash[document2][document1] = similarity
```

Because we now have a "any-to-any" relation in the double-hash, we can find any cluster that a document is in simply by looking at the "m"'s of that document. Any two with the same m number will be in a cluster.

Example of one such group:

```
define get_groups_from_document(doc, similarity_double_hash)
    groups = new hash(default = new list)
    foreach sim_score, hash_key in similarity_double_hash[doc]
        groups[sim_score].append(hash_key) #Remember, hash_key is the other document
    return groups
```

The groups hash that is returned is a pointer for a value of m to the documents that is part of that group, originating from a document. The other documents are guaranteed to have a score to the other documents in the group that are **at least** m. It is not guaranteed to be exactly m.

If you start from another document, the same value of m can, and probably will, have other documents in the list.

If you want to get the largest clusters for a given m, then you must figure out which document to originate from to get the largest cluster. Also, a document can be part of multiple clusters. If you do not want that, then you are back at the beginning with the hard problem of graph clustering.

To find the largest groups for each given m, you can do this:

```
all_groups = new hash
foreach document in all_documents
    all_groups[document] = get_groups_from_document(document, similarity_double_hash)

max_groups = new hash
foreach group in all_groups
    foreach score, document_list in group
        if max_groups[score].length < document_list.length
            max_groups[score] = document_list

foreach score, document_list in max_groups
    print "Largest group for " + score + " is " + document_list.to_string
```

Now you have a fine list of the largest groups for any given m, but as I said, documents can be in multiple lists and a "m" group here is really "m-or-greater", not "exactly m".

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought of a similar approach but unfortunately it is O(n^3)

Comment: Yeah. Well, clustering is a hard problem, as I mentioned.